# postgresql rename a foreignkey after renaming a table

Tags: postgresql

I renamed a table, and apparently a foreignkey in it doesn't get changed, and causing problems, 
Although when I `\d error` I get:
`"error_test_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (test_id) REFERENCES test(id) ON DELETE CASCADE`

Which the only relation to `error` name, is the name (weird)

Anyway - I have no problem deleting the foreignkey and recreating it, but I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: It seems worth mentioning that technically the name of the foreign key is in no way related to the names of the objects it refers from/to. It is a quite useful convention though to give the foreign keys names that let the human user derive their purpose. Therefore in such a case I recommend that you also rename the foreign key. Luckily an answer for that is already present :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL 9.2 or newer, you can use [`RENAME CONSTRAINT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/sql-altertable.html):

```
ALTER TABLE name RENAME CONSTRAINT "error_test_id_fkey" TO "the_new_name_fkey";
```